# Impossible to install Ubuntu from USB device

Tags: system-installation

I have created a live usb device with Unetbootin in order to install(tried with 15.10 and 16 LTS) ubuntu on a laptop.
But when I start up the laptop and choose to boot on USB, I am getting a "BOOT ERROR" message.

How can I force the laptop to boot on the USB device?

Comment: Are there any other messages, or only two words "BOOT ERROR"? Could you provide a photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things could go wrong.  Your USB key could have a hardware fault, but probably not.  Still, try another USB key if you have one.  You should also try to create a USB live device with something else than Unetbootin.  Try your USB key on a different computer, a friend's computer perhaps (no harm, it will only load Ubuntu, not install it).

Finally, there could be a problem with the BIOS/UEFI of your laptop.  Do you have the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

You should try another software like hans says (I recommend universal USB installer)

Also look if your pendrive has the archive "bootx64.efi" on the efi folder. Sometimes the system wont boot/install cause there is no such file. If there is a "grubx64.efi" rename it.

Comment: I finally used rufus, and everything works fine. Thanks all for your help